# UTFGrid and line features: UTFGrid not consistently triggering mouse events for line features

Tags: leaflet, line, mapnik, utfgrid

[**Update**: My first solution works (notes below), but I'm still interested in responses to the second solution I suggested.]

---

**Original Post:**

Has anyone experienced and resolved difficulties with UTFGrid tiles of linestring feature data?

**I'm encountering three issues:**

1. The **"mouse targets" for the line features are extraordinarily thin**, and I have to circle the mouse around the lines to trigger anything at all. Even when I find the target area, it's difficult to follow the line and stay on target because the hit area is razor-thin.
2. In some places, **the linear grid target seems to be a slightly offset** from the rendered line feature. The trouble here is it makes the interaction counter-intuitive for end users.
3. Line **features seem to be entirely missing from some areas** of the grid. If I slowly move the mouse pointer in a circle over a line, I can usually catch the hit area and get a hover popup. However in other areas--where the features are not even dense--there is simply no hit response, leaving me to believe the feature is entirely absent from the grid.

I'm using Tilestache and Mapnik to render my grid tiles, and these are the corresponding mapnik stylesheet (xml) and tilestache config (cfg/json) file entries, respectively:

**Mapnik stylesheet for linear UTFGrid layer (XML):**

```
    <Layer name="watermains_utfgrid" srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over">
        <StyleName>style</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
          <Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="host">localhost</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="port">5432</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="dbname">db_name</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="user">db_user</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="password">db_password</Parameter>
          <Parameter name="table">watermains</Parameter>
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>
```

**Tilestache config entry for UTFGrid layer (JSON):**

```json
"layers":
  {
    "watermains-utfgrid":
    {
        "provider":
        {
            "name": "mapnik grid",
            "mapfile": "/etc/TileStache/map_styles/utfgrid_layers.xml",
            "fields": ["handle","watermaindia","type","est_year","subdivision"],
            "layer_index": 0,
            "scale": 4
        }
    }
 }
```

I have two ideas for how I might resolve these issues:

1. **Create a view of the layer table that buffers the geometry.** Rendering it as a polygon should yield a larger hit area, then I can reference the view for the Mapnik grid layer.

[Update per above] Creating a view that buffers the geometry (I used a buffer radius of "4", which is 4 meters since the data is in EPSG3857) solved all three problems, however the grids rendered considerably slow and I suspect at an undesirable expense of CPU/RAM. Storing the view as a table made a remarkable improvement to rendering speed and resource consumption. Although IMO it seems unnecessary to do this for every dataset of line features. As such I'm still hoping someone may be aware of something I should be doing differently, such as adjusting the `scale` value as proposed in my second idea, below.

2. **"Tweak" the `scale` value in the tilestache cfg entry.** This one is more mysterious, as I don't understand how that scale value affects the grid. For this reason, I actually suspect tweaking the scale is the way to go, and it's on this point I'm optimistic someone might have some useful insight.

I'm pretty sure option #1 will provide a work-around, but before I setup a bunch of grid layers against views with buffered geometries, I wanted to see if anyone else has bumped into similar issues and resolved it by adjusting the tilestache `scale` value ..or anything else I may have overlooked!